# How do I parameterize a Postgres array value in Node / pg-pool

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgpool, node-pg-pool

I am querying an array column (`style text[]`) using the contains operator `@>`. My raw query is:

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE style @> '{Acoustic}'
```

When I drop this into node (using [pg-pool](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#poolquery)) and attempt to parameterize it, the braces surrounding the value reference seem to prevent it from working properly. Note these examples:

```
const style = 'Acoustic';

// this works, but I don't want to in-line like this:
const { rows } = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE style @> '{` + style + `}'`);

// this fails with 'error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0'
const { rows } = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE style @> '{$1}'`, [style]);
```

What's the proper way to parameterize this?

Comment: Note that I got this working with a different kind of query: `pool.query('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE $1 = ANY (style)', [style]);`, but I'd like to know if there's a way to work with the form above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const { rows } = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE style @> '{$1}'`, [style]);
> ```

The $1 here, being in quotes, is just regarded as part of the string, not as a substitutable variable.  If you wish to pass in a scalar and have it treated as an array, you should be able to do it this way:

```
const { rows } = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE style @> ARRAY[$1]`, [style]);
```

An alternative might be to have node.js bind an array directly (not tested):

```
const { rows } = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM songs WHERE style @> $1`, [[style]]);
```

Comment: Both options you gave work, and make it clearer to me how to work with array columns. Thanks!